# Rails starter project renders template in the wrong path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have just set up my rails dev environment and created a new rails project with the `rails new` command. Everything starts up correctly when I run `bundle exec rails s` except the rendered template is `/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/templates/rails/welcome/index.html.erb` instead of my actual project `/home/ubuntu/github/project/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`.

Making a change to my project is not reflected on the server either. It must be a stupid mistake I've made somewhere but I just can't seem to figure out.

Example request log:

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-12-20 17:05:52 +0000
Processing by Rails::WelcomeController#index as HTML
  Rendering /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties- 
5.2.2/lib/rails/templates/rails/welcome/index.html.erb
  Rendered /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties- 
5.2.2/lib/rails/templates/rails/welcome/index.html.erb (1.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 5ms (Views: 4.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Comment: If you've installed a Rails gem that operates as an engine then in order to override the content you must create a file in exactly the same relative path as the engine expects. Remember "template" (or view file) and "layout" are two different but related things. In this case `app/views/rails/welcome/index.html.erb`.

Comment: If that controller has `layout false` set then you won't get the layout at all.

Comment: Do you have a controller and a root route? No. Well then it is rendering the Welcome to Rails page. Congratulations it works. Now you need to generate a controller, add an action, route to it, and add a view.

Comment: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a route and controller for that route. You're looking at the default page that Rails renders when installed and run.